# Passing an array values from html into flash array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, flash, actionscript

anyone knows how to pass an array values from an HTML into flash? Well, to begin I'll discuss what am I doing. I edited a twitter widget javascript which search tweets based on the hashtag I needed then passing it on an array per tweet and then displaying it using a `<div>` it updates once every 5 minutes. Now I want to display those tweets on a dynamic text on Flash. Let's say I will have 5 dynamic text placed on my flash file then; I want each of those dynamic text to have the tweets I have based on on my HTML arrays to be displayed in random.

For better understanding (I think?):

HTML: Var Array --> Flash: Var Array (How to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flash vars or a php-page to read the array from. Have look at the following link for more information:

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=181683

Comment: Thanks, but as much as possible I don't want to apply PHP or any scripting language just pure HTML on the page.

Comment: That the flashvars way: http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html

Comment: FlashVars can only be used at load time of the swf and is not what he needs.

Comment: For now this one can do, still learning about this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'funcName', callBackFunc)` function in the AS3 code. Then in your JavaScript you can do something like `flashObj.funcName( myArray );`